# How do I rewrite a messy URL as a clean URL using HTACCESS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm trying to turn all pages into clean URLs (so that site.com/new/index.php?page=hello turns in to site.com/new/hello). After doing research, it seems making an HTACCESS file handle path rewriting is the best approach. I've researched this for months and have not yet found a reliable solution.

I've tried a bunch of ways to do this and none are responding. I've even tried it on different Apache servers to see if there was some issue. I've contacted the hosts and it appears all settings are fine.

I've tried a few approaches and variations thereof. I've also tried changing my permissions, changing my settings in cPanel and WHM, and also placing the HTACCESS file in different directories. Nothing has been able to change the URL, though other commands in my HTACCESS file are running, so I know the file is being read.

Here's code I've tried so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?page=$1
```

And this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

It appears not to work, as the URL remains the same regardless of whether I've added this script or not.

The site seems completely unaffected by the addition of this code. The HTACCESS file is entirely clean, and there are no other HTACCESS files on the "partition" which would affect it. To replicate, try using the above code in an HTACCESS file in any directory.

I would expect the code to rewrite the URL to a clean format, as it seems most sites recommend code like this to change the URL the way I need. However my site preserves the URL with the page=hello variable as if no HTACCESS script is present.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: There is nothing we can say here, since we have very little information. Statements like "none are responding", "was some issue", "It appears not to work" do not really help. One thing that clearly stands out is that you apparently want the URL shown in the browser to change (so you want a redirection), but you do not implement a redirection but in internal rewriting. Apart from that you will need to start debugging, since only you have access to your system and know about the specific situation. So check your http server's error log file, use rewrite logging, check your browser's console.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'm a little confused. You said I provided very little information - I thought I provided too much! Also, "it appears not to work" is about the best I can do as nothing's showing in my logs. If I did know why, I'd probably be able to figure out the fix. This HTACCESS approach is also a suggestion. I'm trying to build a site with clean URLs (which almost EVERY site in existence seems to do successfully) and I'm trying to put together the best approach. Surprisingly, there's very little information on the topic.

Comment: Actually there is _tons_ of information, _thousands_ of answers here on SO, _countless_ tutorials. That is not the issue. You have indeed given some information, but it is vague, fuzzy. We would need precise information to be able to help. An example: you write in the comment: "nothing's showing in my logs. "... You did not say so in your question. Nor did you say _what_ log.